# Using Global Variables in Y86 Assembly

Tags: assembly, global-variables, cpu-registers, y86

I'm trying to write a program that creates a sum of all inclusive integers between x and y, with the sum, y, and x being global variables. I'm running into problems when I try to assign the x and y to local registers (my simulator assigns the values of 0x60 and 0x64 to the local registers as opposed to 1 and 4) as well as taking the summed value and transferring that to the global variable of sum. Usually I try to find helpful guides online, but Y86 is such a sparingly used language that there is next to nothing.

My code:

```
.pos 0

init:   irmovl Stack, %esp  //Set up stack pointer
irmovl Stack, %ebp  //Set up base pointer
call main       //call main program
halt            //Terminate program


main:   pushl %ebp      //setup
rrmovl %esp, %ebp

pushl %ebx      //declaring x local register
irmovl x, %ebx      
pushl %esi      //declaring y local register
irmovl y, %esi      
pushl %eax      //declaring sum
irmovl sum, %eax
pushl %edi      //constant of 1
irmovl $1, %edi

L2:
subl %ebx, %esi     // %esi = y-x
jl L3           // ends function if x > y

irmovl y, %esi      // %esi = y
addl %ebx, %eax     // sum += x
addl %edi, %ebx     // x++
jmp L2          // go to beginning of loop

rmmovl %eax, (%eax) //value assigned to sum global variable

L3: 
rrmovl %ebp, %esp   //finish
popl %ebx       
popl %esi
popl %edi
popl %eax
popl %ebp

ret




.align 4
x: .long 1
y: .long 4
sum: .long 0

.pos 0x200
Stack: .long 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out why the registers were getting the wrong values (I was sending them the memory locations with irmovl instead of the values with mrmovl) and in a similar vein, how to assign the value to the global variable sum (rmmovl %eax, sum).

It was a matter of addressing the content as opposed to location